# Can I still create new households after starting the game?

Tags: the-sims-4

Researching this on the internet was very difficult, and I ended up without the answer I’m looking for.
I am trying to find out whether it is possible to create a new household once I have started playing in a town with two already created households.
I am asking as I wouldn’t want to start all over again in case I am required to make all households I want to, before playing in the town.

Answer (score 2):

You can still create new households from the neighborhood screen, at any point of time in a game worlds existence

[image: Create Household]

---

So I created a new world as a test for this, with heavy use of randomization.

Meet Emanuel Bush, he's a funny bro who wants to tell jokes.  He's just been moved into <s>a shack</s> an amazing new home.

[image: Bush House]

Going back to the world screen, I made sure to save my <s>horrendous</s> lovely cheap starter house.

[image: Save to Worlds]

I noticed that he was all alone, and may get lonely without neighbors.

[image: Isolated Shack]

So, I created a new household to move in.

[image: Create Household]

With a bit more random button clicks, welcome another bro, Amber Ruffin, to the neighborhood.  She has a nice home next door imported from the gallery.

[image: The Bros]

Life was well and all were happy.  But what's a good sims story without an evil person?  After letting Emanuel and Amber chat for a while, I decided another house was needed.  I saved and exited to worlds and created a new household.

[image: Create Household]

Margarita Knutson.  She is the bane of the neighborhood.  Being a public enemy, hot headed, evil, kleptomaniac.  She's here to ruin peoples day.

[image: Public Enemy]

And she's already off to a great start in the neighborhood.

[image: Being Mean]

So yes, it is definitely possible to create new sims at any point in time to suit your needs.  It can be a great plot development for new sims to move into the neighborhood.

Another neat feature is you can [evict households to add background sims](https://www.reddit.com/r/thesims/comments/2f7gru/the_sims_4_how_to_edit_the_townies_list/), so creating a household, moving them in, and evicting them, but they will still roam that world every so often.

Comment: Any reason for the down vote?